# is it possible to run chrome in debug mode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, logging, webkit, google-chrome-devtools

Firstly I'm really not sure if this is a question for Super-User or Stack-Overflow. It may certainly useful for other developers but it's not a specific code question.

In Google Chrome is there a way to look at render engine exceptions or general debugging info? I have some code which i'm 99% certain is crashing the render/repaint engine for chrome but (i'm on a mac) in the Console.app I don't get notifications for the exception. I'm wondering if theres a way of forcing chrome to be much more verbose in it's logging? Perhaps it's a webkit thing rather than chrome specific.

Let me know if this really isn't for stack overflow and I'll remove/close the question like I said I'm aware it's not code specific.

Comment: Have you read this: http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging#TOC-Single-process-mode?

Answer (score 5):

Yes!

You can start chrome from the command line on a mac. See a previous question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/157484/start-google-chrome-on-mac-with-command-line-switches)

something like this:

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`

You can also pass a flag to make chrome output to a log file by appending:

`--enable-logging --v=1`

This should write a log file `chrome_debug.log` which lives somewhere in your `~/.config/` directory.

Then you can tail that log. My command for that is:

`$ tail -F ~/.config/chromium/chrome_debug.log`

Your path to the log file may be different.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

In a similar way as [Rimian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45930178/2271388), in Windows you can also start Chrome from command line enabling logging. Just open CMD and type:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
chrome --enable-logging --v=1
```

The log file `chrome_debug.log` is in `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`. Notice you have to replace  for your username.

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure whether I understood it correctly but maybe you want to check out chromium.org HOW-TO for mac rather than windows. you have two possibilities to debug the renderer process

a) Run Chrome in a single process
or
b) Attach XCode's debugger to a renderer process after launch

They are described in detail [here](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-os-x). Hope that helps

EDIT: updated the link

Comment: Broken link. Thank why it is always a good idea to add the relevant pieces of information inside the answer.

Comment: @GilbertoTorrezan thanks for noticing (the structure of the urls has changed, the correct link was in the suggestions though)... still I did not want to just like copy paste the whole block there